# Repeat control, pass db and view in order to improve performance?

Tags: xpages

I have the following repeat control showing all products:

```
<xp:repeat id="rptProduct" rows="16" value="#{vwProduct}"
        var="productRow">
        <xp:panel styleClass="linkPanel" id="panel1">
            <xp:text escape="false" id="imgHTML">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getImgURLForProduct(productRow.getDocument());}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad"
                submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh"></xp:eventHandler></xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

Where getImgURLForProduct builds a URL from another database:

```
function getImgURLForProduct(doc:NotesDocument) {
    var resourceDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(getWebServer(), applicationScope.aspCRMResourceDBPath);
    var strReturnVal:String = "<a style='text-decoration: none;' href='#'>";

    if (resourceDB != null) {
        if (resourceDB.isOpen()) {
            var vwResource:NotesView = resourceDB.getView("vwLookupAttachmentsForPrimaryImg");

            if (vwResource != null) {
                var pictureDoc:NotesDocument = vwResource.getDocumentByKey(doc.getItemValueString("fldProductCode"), true);

                if (pictureDoc != null) {
                    if (pictureDoc.hasItem("fldThumbImage")) {
                        var rtiLockPicture:NotesRichTextItem = pictureDoc.getFirstItem("fldThumbImage");

                        var eos:java.util.Vector = rtiLockPicture.getEmbeddedObjects();

                        if (eos.isEmpty() == false) {
                            var eosi:java.util.Iterator = eos.iterator();

                            while (eosi.hasNext()) {
                                var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eosi.next();

                                if (eo.getType() == NotesEmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
                                    var strImageFile:String = "/" +  applicationScope.aspCRMResourceDBPath + "/0/" + pictureDoc.getUniversalID() + "/$file/" + eo.getSource(); 
                                    strReturnVal += "<img src='" + strImageFile + "' alt='" + eo.getSource() + "' border='0' width='105'>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    strReturnVal += "<br /><br /><span>" + doc.getItemValueString("fldProductCode") +  "</span>";
    strReturnVal += "</a>";
    return strReturnVal;
}
```

I was wondering how I can improve the code so that the db and the view are not initialised for each and every item within a repeat control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to store the view from a different database in a dataContext. I'm not sure how recycle-safe dataContexts are, but it may be safe to store Domino objects in them. There's a good section in Mastering XPages about dataContexts. That was very useful for me.

Comment: Thanks Paul - much appreciated - will research it further and see if I can improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go would be to change the notesview in the database where you retrieve the documentdata from. This view contains all the data you need (except ofc. richtext values) and on top of that a column containing the computed url you are generating in this piece of code. That way you dont have to open a secondary database for every document you are referencing.

Another approach would be to improve your code by adding some means of caching. If the getImageFromUrl method always opens the same database (on the same server etc.) you could change your could like this.

Warning this code comes without any waranty and has no error handling whatsoever ;)

```
    function getImgURLForProduct(doc:NotesDocument) {
        var docid = doc.getUniversalID();
if(inCache(docID){
   return fromCache(docid);
} 

        var resourceDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(getWebServer(), applicationScope.aspCRMResourceDBPath);
        var strReturnVal:String = "<a style='text-decoration: none;' href='#'>";

        if (resourceDB != null) {
            if (resourceDB.isOpen()) {
                var vwResource:NotesView = resourceDB.getView("vwLookupAttachmentsForPrimaryImg");

                if (vwResource != null) {
                    var pictureDoc:NotesDocument = vwResource.getDocumentByKey(doc.getItemValueString("fldProductCode"), true);

                    if (pictureDoc != null) {
                        if (pictureDoc.hasItem("fldThumbImage")) {
                            var rtiLockPicture:NotesRichTextItem = pictureDoc.getFirstItem("fldThumbImage");

                            var eos:java.util.Vector = rtiLockPicture.getEmbeddedObjects();

                            if (eos.isEmpty() == false) {
                                var eosi:java.util.Iterator = eos.iterator();

                                while (eosi.hasNext()) {
                                    var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eosi.next();

                                    if (eo.getType() == NotesEmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
                                        var strImageFile:String = "/" +  applicationScope.aspCRMResourceDBPath + "/0/" + pictureDoc.getUniversalID() + "/$file/" + eo.getSource(); 
                                        strReturnVal += "<img src='" + strImageFile + "' alt='" + eo.getSource() + "' border='0' width='105'>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        strReturnVal += "<br /><br /><span>" + doc.getItemValueString("fldProductCode") +  "</span>";
        strReturnVal += "</a>";
        toCache(strReturnVal);
        return strReturnVal;
    }

function inCache(strKey){
  if(!sessionScope.containsKey("urlcache")){
    sessionScope.put("urlcache",new java.util.HashMap());
}
  var cache = sessionScope.get("urlcache");
  cache.containsKey(strKey);
}

function fromCache(strKey){
  var cache = sessionScope.get("urlcache");
  return cache.get(strKey);
}

function toCache(strKey,strValue){
  if(!sessionScope.containsKey("urlcache")){
    sessionScope.put("urlcache",new java.util.HashMap());
}
  var cache = sessionScope.get("urlcache");
  cache.put(strKey,strValue);
}
```

By checking first if there is an cache entry available for the doc you are referencing you dont need to open the database again.

Comment: Thanks for both the options. With the first option, I would have to generate the URL when the pictureDoc is saved I guess and update the value accordingly - it's a good work-around, might consider that. The second suggestion is interesting as well! Thank you.

Comment: I decided to combine datacontexts based on Paul's suggestion with your second suggestion to cache the results - many thanks.

Comment: I also fixed issues with the code: var docID:String = doc.getUniversalID();
    
    if (inCache(docID)) {
       return fromCache(docID);
    }
    
    and
    
    toCache(docID, strReturnVal);

Comment: On top of the code i posted above you could further optimize it by using a java.lang.stringbuffer object to optimize performance a bit as described here http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-0324-javaperf.html

Comment: Implementing StringBuffer now - I stumbled onto this a while ago and forgot!! many thanks for the reminder!